# Sumar dias de una fecha en json a python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, date, datetime

Hola estoy intentando sumar 22 dias a esta fecha desde un archivo json:{“date”:“2020-03-30”}

pero al convertirlo a string en python no me deja sumarlo

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json

f = open('date.json', 'r')
content = f.read()
jsondecoded = json.loads(content)
x = json.dumps(jsondecoded)
print(x)


days_plus = x + str(datetime.timedelta(days=22))
print(days_plus)
```

pero me da el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/usr/Documents/Workspace/prueba/fecha.py", line 11, in 
> days_plus = (str(x) + str(datetime.timedelta(days=22)))
> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Si alguien me puede orientar, para que la salida de este programa me sume los 22 dias asi o lo mas cercano posible:

> 

```
input: {“date”:“2020-03-30”}
output: 2020-04-21
```

> 

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente tienes que convertir de texto a datetime y luego ya podrás hacer la adición de los días.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json

# f = open('date.json', 'r')
# content = f.read()
# jsondecoded = json.loads(content)
# x = json.dumps(jsondecoded)
# print(x)
x = {"date":"2020-03-30"}


days_plus = datetime.strptime(x["date"], "%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=22)
print(days_plus)
```

Saludos..

Comment: Gracias, funciono de esa manera, aunque lo configure para que consuma los .json... Saludos

Comment: Claro, es que como no tengo tu json simplemente simule uno, saludos